# fillna() depending on column type function

Tags: python, pandas

I am spinning my wheels on a function which is supposed to take a data frame, iterate through the columns and depending on the type of column, fillna with either 0's for numeric types, 'na' for string types, a default date for date types and False for bools.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,np.nan,3,np.nan],
                        'b':['abc',np.nan,'def','hij'],
                        'c':[True,False,np.nan,np.nan,],
                        'd': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', np.nan, '2020-01-04']})
```

Looks like:

```
df
Out[96]: 
     a    b      c           d
0  1.0  abc   True  2020-01-01
1  NaN  NaN  False  2020-01-02
2  3.0  def    NaN         NaN
3  NaN  hij    NaN  2020-01-04
```

I attempted to create a function to fill nan values:

```
def handle_nans(df, d):
    """
    :param df: a dataframe
    :param d: current iterations run_date
    :return: a data frame with replacement of na values as either 0 for numeric fields, 'na' for text and False for bool
    """
    for f in df:
        if df[f].dtype == "int64":
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(0)
        elif df[[f]].columns == 'date':
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(d)
        elif df[[f]].columns == 'sampling':
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(False)
        else:
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(0)
    return(df)
```

Tried:

```
handle_nans(df, '2019-01-01')
Out[100]: 
     a    b      c           d
0  1.0  abc   True  2020-01-01
1  0.0    0  False  2020-01-02
2  3.0  def      0           0
3  0.0  hij      0  2020-01-04
```

So, this appears to have correctly converted the numeric columns to 0. But I wanted to change string types to 'na', date types to the default date and boolean types to True.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @anky_91, added reproducible example, Let me know if this helps clarify what I'm asking?

Comment: Where does the data come from? _Col a, which is numeric has the Nan replaced with 0_ I can't see any `NaN` values in the column a.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Don't add `NaN` values for the fun of it. What does your data actually look like?

Comment: hi @AMC I have updated by question with a new `ex_df` that contains a mix of nan and None values

Comment: The NaN values stem from an outer join where one of my df's contain a  id that does not appear in another

Comment: Also, I don't think looping over the columns is a good idea here. It's probably best to select the columns manually. The column names in your example are not the same as in your description of the task.

Comment: _The NaN values stem from an outer join where one of my df's contain a id that does not appear in another_ Where do the `None` values come from?

Comment: @AMC looking at my actual data now, there are no None values in fact, just nans. I did not grasp the difference at the time of posting. So missing strings and numeric and bool data in these cases come back as nan

Comment: @DougFir Can you update your post? It might be worth cleaning up the entire thing at some point, because it's already looking quite heavy.

Comment: Pandas uses `object` for datatypes that do not have a native value that can be used to represent missing values. For numeric types it uses `float64` since it has NaN. If you have a column on `int64` and add a row with missing value in that place, the column will become `float64`. If you have a column of `bool`, adding a missing value will turn it into `object`. String columns are always `object`.

Comment: If a column is not the expected type but `object`, it either means that there are missing values or that the parser wasn't able to deduce the proper type and used string instead.

Comment: @AMC done, let me know if this looks better?

Comment: What do you mean by _I wanted to change string types to 'na', date types to the default date and boolean types to True_? Again, I urge you to abandon the idea of iterating over the columns like this. I don't think it makes much sense when you consider the nature and purpose of Pandas Dataframes, and it will probably be hellish to get right.

Comment: @AMC I mean that if there's a NaN in a numeric field, replace it with 0, if there's a NaN in a string field, replace it with 'na', if there's a NaN in a date field, replace it with the default date. While I could just pass the name of the columns to work with for each data type, basing it on the data type itself makes the function longer lasting without having to update it if the fields in the script updated. R has a great set of tools for this in the tidyverse: `mutate_if()`, `select_if()` etc

Comment: _basing it on the data type itself makes the function longer lasting without having to update it if the fields in the script updated._ Right, except that actually finding the data type of the columns is going to get quite hacky. Can you provide some more context for this? What is this data? Where does it come from? What is the program for?

Comment: @AMC I will take your advice and rewrite my function with input parameters based on a list of fields for each data type `handle_nans(numerics = ['my', 'numric', 'cols'], str_fields = ['my', 'string', 'fields'], bools = ['my', 'bool', ''fields])`

Comment: @DougFir That's a good idea. Do you expect the columns to change very often?

Comment: @AMC they will change once or twice a month. I can update the function manually. Would have been convenient if there was a solid way of doing this but I want to pick my battles with pandas carefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206200/discussion-between-amc-and-doug-fir).

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification needed in your function:

```
# set to timestamp
ex_df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(ex_df['d'])

def handle_nas(df, default_date='2020-01-01'):
    """
    :param df: a dataframe
    :param d: current iterations run_date
    :return: a data frame with replacement of na values as either 0 for numeric fields, 'na' for text and False for bool
    """
    for f in df.columns:

        # integer
        if df[f].dtype == "int":
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(0)

        # dates
        elif df[f].dtype == '<M8[ns]':
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(pd.to_datetime(default_date))

        # boolean
        elif df[f].dtype == 'bool':
            df[f] = df[f].fillna(True)

        # string
        else:
            df[f] = df[f].fillna('na')

    return df

     a    b      c         d
0   1  abc   True 2020-01-01
1   2   na  False 2020-01-02
2   3  def     na 2020-01-01
3  na  hij   True 2020-01-04
```

You can replace the possible na's by doing this:

```
possible_nas = ['na','None','null','nan','none'] # add whatever you think are nas
ex_df = ex_df.applymap(lambda x: None if x in possible_nas else x)
```

> > Why NA values are a pain in the data frames ?

```
# sample dfs
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['nan','bl','bo'], 'b':[None, 1, 2], 'c': ['none','null','go']})

# check the type of nulls
type(df['b'][0])
numpy.float64
```

And, none of the value in `possible_nas` match this type. So, such values will never be replaced.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great! On my df it's not working for the bool one though? Do I need to set the datatype do you think first? Like you did on the top with to_datetime?

Comment: Make sure the null value are actually `None` in your dataframe and not of some other form like "None" or "nan" or "NA"

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's nan actually. Fillna will not work for an?

Comment: pandas need to recognize them as null value, you can fix this while reading the dataframe, set all possible values which should be read as null, do something like `pd.read_csv(file_name, na_values = ['','nan','None',.....])`

Comment: Ah. I don't read the df from csv though it's a result from a api. I wonder if there' a general nan eplace so I can replace all nan with None to get the function tow work

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion using `possible_nas = ['na','None','null','nan','none'] # add whatever you think are nas
ex_df = ex_df.applymap(lambda x: None if x in possible_nas else x)` I tried that but when I use that the function does not work on any of those fields, instead they all just return as 'na', like the `else:` part of the function is the only part that get's applied

Comment: the function works on the given example, could you add some testcase where it is failing so I can also check on my side.

Comment: _I wonder if there' a general nan eplace so I can replace all nan with None to get the function tow work_ Don't. `NaN` is the Pandas standard, not `None`.

Comment: Hi, added example with NaN's now. Sorry for the poor initial example. If you apply your function to this new ex_df, you will see that the nans get returned as na whereas I'd like numeric columns to be replaced with 0

Comment: check the edit, make sure you fix the type of all null values.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Going to leave this q open for a little while but it sounds like pandas is not really suited to this type of operation. Regarding your edit, if I replace_nas with your suggestion, it will overwrite the na's that should remain for the string fields

Answer (score 0):

To identify data types you can apply the funtions `type` or `isinstace` to each value. For example:

```
   float   datetime  bool string
0    1.0 2018-03-10  True    foo
1    NaN        NaT   NaN   None

df.applymap(type)
```

Output:

```
             float                                           datetime  \
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...   
1  <class 'float'>      <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>   

                 bool              string  
0      <class 'bool'>       <class 'str'>  
1     <class 'float'>  <class 'NoneType'>
```

You can use the following approach:

```
mapping = [(float, 0), (bool, False), (str, 'na'), (pd.Timestamp, pd.Timestamp('20200118'))]

df_type = df.applymap(type)
df_notna = df.notna()
for t, v in mapping:
    mask = ((df_type == t) & df_notna).any()
    for col in df.columns[mask]:
        df[col].fillna(v, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   float   datetime   bool string
0    1.0 2018-03-10   True    foo
1    0.0 2020-01-18  False     na
```

As you can see the time column should be parsed first otherwise it will be identified as a string.